# How to get exact results from Google search API as real Google search gives

Tags: google-search-api

I want to get response from Google search API. For example, if I request th query "Benefits of Sport", the API should return about this query but now it is returning something else. Not accurate/exact results I am getting. Please help me to do request, how can I include websites to my search? Example," khanacademy.org" or anything else. Thanks

I have tried many times by setting query but it returns something different

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={myKey}&cx={myCX}&num=1&q=Benefits+of+sport
```

Expected Result: Something about sport.
Actual Result: "Tyson Fury v Deontay Wilder: Briton benefits from base Lennox ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer my question because I found a answer. So, in order to get exact results, we can add sites such as khanacademy.org, stackoverflow.com or any other sites to search from this sites